# Backbone with Rails - include order

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, asset-pipeline

After a couple of hours of trying to understand why the same code that works stand-alone does not work when it is inside rails, I realized that rails include the collection file before the model file, and it raises the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I dug and found out using console that model was undefined.

The temporary solution I found was to include files one by one in my `application.js`, but I cannot believe that this is the only solution. It is far of being elegant, and when code become larger it will be impossible to track it.

Somebody has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I second @BillyChan 's suggestion. I've been using it all the time.

No, it does not make the code messy. But if your model file becomes really big. You may wanna revisit your code again to see if anything can be extracted to a helper, or even a new model.

Well if you really don't wanna do that...I assume you put collections and models in different folders (if not, it's messier than putting model/collection in one file, IMO), you can always require the model folder first in your application.js

```
//= require_tree './backbone/models'
//= require_tree './backbone/collections'
//= require_tree './backbone/views'
```

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to put model and collection in same file with model at first.

Comment: It's Javascript, not Ruby. Same pattern in Rails can't be applied everywhere. And messy or not depends on the developer.